# Java: How to set a default for "T" in SomeClass<T>?

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to specify a default type for a generic template?

Let's say I have a `Monkey` class. Monkeys can live in different `Environment`s, such as `Jungle` or `Zoo`:

```
    public class Monkey<T extends Environment>
    {
        T home;
        ...

        public T getHome()
        {
            return home;
        }  
    }
```

Is there a way to specify a default for `T`, so I can use the type `Monkey` instead of `Monkey<?>` without getting a compiler warning?

**EDIT**

In other words, is there a way to get rid of the "raw type" warning without having to explicitly suppress it?

Comment: Yes, I guess 'raw type' is the default.  The only problem is the warnings.

Comment: can someone check is this answer correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466553/extending-arraylist-with-determined-default-member-type

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Generic parameters don't have default values. You could re-organize your type hierarchy so that there's a GenericMonkey and a DefaultMonkey that sets the generic parameter to your desired default.

Answer (score 10):

No you can't:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

*Generic type parameters cannot have default arguments.*

What about making something like this:

```
public class Monkey extends Monkey<YourType>
```

Obviusly you'll "waste" the ability to inherit.

**EDIT 1:**
Another interesting thing is do the reverse of what I suggested,

```
public class Monkey<T> extends Monkey
```

In this case all generics class Monkey inherits Monkey, in some cases, this is a very interesting thing (expecially when you notice that some instance-methods fits in all classes without requiring the generic). This approach is used in Castle ActiveRecord (I've seen it used in C#, not in Java), and I find it beautiful.

Comment: Do both of these have to be in different files (I assume so because in java there can only be one public class per file)? In that case what name do you choose (Since one is Monkey<T> and other MOnkey.

Comment: Well this is not a problem I really think about, but you can name the file that contains Monkey (no generic params) only "Monkey". And the generic monkey MonkeyGeneric or Monkey_T_ as you prefer

Comment: Isn't the java file name supposed to be the same as the name of the public class? I was basically curious about what name you would pick for Monkey<T> if there is already a class that is called as Monkey.java.

Comment: I really don't know this, I think it's a convention. As I stated in question I've seen using it in C# and not in Java. Sorry I can't help you :(

Answer (score 4):

Jen, your question  doesn't put any context around why you want to use a generics. It would really be helpful if you stated what it is you are trying to do and why you are using generics. Generics exist IMHO *mainly* to avoid having to do class casts everywhere when putting things into and taking them out of collections that are designed to be generic holders of types. This *kinda* implies iteration over a bunch of things, but not necessarily.

My point is, I didn't see any part of your class or code that required being able to create a custom version of the monkey class that required iterating over environments. If this is not the case, you probably don't even need generics. Instead, you probably want dependency injection. The monkey class should have a constructor that takes an environment. Environment is an interface (or simple base class). The interface has several default operations like getBathroomLocation() and getFoodLocation(). Instead of using generics to create a type of monkey that lives in the zoo, you create a monkey and inject the dependency of which environment it lives in.

```
Monkey monkey = new Monkey(new CostaRicaJungle());
```

Later on, you can set this environment to something different. The wild monkey gets captured, and you now do

```
monkey.setEnvironment(new BronxZoo());
```

Later, the monkey gets an living condition upgrade, and you do a

```
monkey.setEnvironment(new SanDiegoZoo());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the base class of the Generic? `Monkey<Environment>` ?

Comment: Environment could be abstract, we don't know this.

Comment: It could, that's why I'm asking. However, shouldn't the generic type be able to be an abstract or even an interface?

Comment: `Environment` will always be concrete.

Answer (score -2):

Java doesn’t support default parameters in general (for methods nor type parameters). It is lame— 1000%.

I love Java, it’s a great language, but we should stop defending it: it is a lame language. There is nothing wrong with wanting default parameters, it would make code easier to read— typically, you don’t need it anyway, but that doesn’t mean we shouldn’t have it.

If classes A and B extends A, then Java should be smart enough to throw an error because Strings aren’t Numbers.

If you want default types, youre going to have to make separated classes or methods. Sucks, but, that’s why we love Java.

Cheers.

Comment: Though your initial answer is correct, when giving answers it's best to stick to an objective answer and leave out subjective commentary.