# Java create instance of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

In C# I can use the class Activator or default(T) but how can i do that in Java?
I have a custom class like

```
public class Foo<T extends FooBase> ...
```

Now i want to create a instance of T(it has a public default ctor). 
I am new in java and I have no idea how I could create a instance of that "type". 
I've tried something like this:

```
T.class.newInstance();
```

but T has no .class? So what can I do?

Comment: what's wrong with calling the constructor like `new Foo<Bar>()` (where `class Bar extends FooBase`) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12407106/1193090 answers your question nicely!

Comment: Looking at your question again, i think you might have a wrong concept of how generics work in java. you should read up on it, e.g. the answer and tutorial linked by Reigo above

Comment: No, you can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101568/java-how-to-set-a-default-for-t-in-someclasst

Answer (score -1):

You can use only existing constructor

```
public class Foo<T extends FooBase>{
    T base= (T) new FooBase();
}
```

Comment: @jlordo  If you have not a constructor FooBase(){}, then of course.

Comment: no, you are missing the `new` keyword.

Comment: Of course, foolish me. I see what must be there, not what is there.

Comment: Now the obvious syntax error is gone. But it still won't compile. The compiler will tell you `Type mismatch: cannot convert from FooBase to T`. Just try it with an easy example.

Comment: @jlordo yes, now I see, it needs (T), too. Thank you. Sorry. I checked it on IDE only now.

Answer (score -4):

Class your_class = new Class() ;

Comment: Fails to include argument for the generic type