# Java get the default value of a type

Tags: java, generics

So I'm writing a program in Java after only using C# for a few years and I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. When creating a `generic<T>` class in C#, if you want to set a variable to the default value of `T`, you use `default(T)`. Is there the same functionality in Java and if so how would I do it?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101568/java-how-to-set-a-default-for-t-in-someclasst

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have an equivalent facility. If you want to pass a value to a generic method you must pass it explicitly, even if you're just invoking the type's default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

the default of T in Java is null, as there is no support for primitive generics. This is actually inline with c#, where default of reference type is null and default of numeric types is 0.