# Extending ArrayList with determined default member type

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

i am new at java, so i don't know what this technique called, and i may be poor at explain things, but i hpe you understand.

Assume i have this two class, Item and it might be extended to ExtendedItem

```
public class Item { }

public class ExtendedItem extends Item {}
```

i want to create collection wrapper for it, so i create a class extended from ArrayList... (Scenario 1)

```
public class DataSet extends ArrayList<Item> {}
```

then initialize it

```
DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
DataSet<ExtendedItem> dataset2  = new DataSet<ExtendedItem >();

dataset1.get(0) // yield Item instance... which is in this case, correct
dataset2.get(0) // also yield Item instance
```

now, when i define DataSet with generic type... (Scenario 2)

```
public class DataSet<T extends Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {}
```

it yielding

```
DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
DataSet<ExtendedItem> dataset2  = new DataSet<ExtendedItem >();

dataset1.get(0) // yield Object instance.... dont't want this
dataset2.get(0) // yield ExtendedItem instance... correct
```

is there any way (scenario) so both data set yield correct type with "Item" as the default type?, like this:

```
DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
DataSet<ExtendedItem> dataset2  = new DataSet<ExtendedItem >();

dataset1.get(0) // yield Item instance
dataset2.get(0) // yield ExtendedItem instance
```

**--------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------**

I might found the solution:

```
public class DataSet<E extends Item> extends ArrayList<E> implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable {
    @Override
    public E get(int i) {
        return super.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return super.size();
    }
}
```

with that:

```
DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
DataSet<ExtendedItem> dataset2  = new DataSet<ExtendedItem >();

dataset1.get(0) // yield Item instance... correct
dataset2.get(0) // yield ExtendedItem instance... correct
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101568/java-how-to-set-a-default-for-t-in-someclasst

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the raw type.

Change

```
DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();
```

to

```
DataSet<Item> dataset1 = new DataSet<Item>();
```

Then `dataset1.get(0)` will return `Item`.

You should also change

```
public class DataSet<T extends Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {}
```

to

```
public class DataSet<T extends Item> extends ArrayList<T> {}
```

Otherwise `dataset2.get(0)` will also return `Item` instead of `ExtendedItem`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i ended up found other solution :)

Comment: @1412 please take heed of Eran's advice. Your solution may appear to work, but has subtle problems.

Comment: thank you for the advice, can you elaborate the problem that might occurred? for educational purpose